# PHP wait for signal and redirect from Android App

Tags: php, android

I am trying to develop an Android application, and I feel kinda stuck in an implementation detail.

I want the application to connect with a web server (LAMP). My PHP page would then wait for a signal from my Android device and redirect the page upon an event being triggered.

After a bit of research, I have deducted that sockets one to this, although I'm not quite sure. The Android device connects to the socket on the server and sends a signal for redirection on event completion. Are there any alternate methods to accomplish this?

Also, my other usage of the server language would be to handle POST requests and submit them to a database. Are there better suited languages compared to PHP?

Comment: I'm not quite sure with the socket thing. The cases where sockets need to be used on android is very rare. In your case, why not doing  classical http requests between the phone and the lamp server? And on the server side, do some ajax polling to update the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a http library included in the SDK.  See the code below for an example.  I use this to login, register, add events to a calendar, and get events.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.Log;

public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

// Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp
// use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
private static String loginURL = "http://xxx.com/android/login.php";
private static String registerURL = "http://xxx.com/android/login.php";
private static String createURL = "http://xxx.com/android/login.php";
private static String getEventURL = "http://xxx.com/android/login.php";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String create_tag = "create_event";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    if(json !=null)
        Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

public JSONObject getEvents(String lon, String lat, String uid, String page){
    // Building Parameters
    Log.e("steve","public JSONObject getEvents(String lon, String lat, String uid)");
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "get_events"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", lon));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", page));
    //Log.e("steve","Get Events");
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(getEventURL, params);
    // return json
    if(json !=null)
        Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

public JSONObject attendEvent(String uid, String eid){
    // Building Parameters

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "attend_event"));

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eid", eid));

    Log.e("steve","U="+uid+"E="+eid);
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(getEventURL, params);
    // return json
    if(json !=null)
        Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}
public JSONObject getAttendance(String uid, String eid){
    // Building Parameters

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "get_attendance"));

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eid", eid));

    Log.e("steve","U="+uid+"E="+eid);
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(getEventURL, params);
    // return json
    if(json !=null)
        Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

public JSONObject createEvent(String name, String edate, String etime, String edesc, String loc, String lon, String lat, String uid){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", create_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", edate));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", etime));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("desc", edesc));        
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loc", loc));        
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", lon));        
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));        
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));        

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(createURL, params);
    if(json !=null)
        Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}

}
```